# How to set sizes of every JPanel in JFrame in full-screen?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

I have a `JFrame` with 3 `JPanel` components like this:

---

```
|                    |                   |
|          1         |                   |
|                    |                   |
|                    |                   |
|____________________|                   |
|                    |        3          |
|         2          |                   |
|                    |                   |
|                    |                   |
|                    |                   |
|____________________|___________________|
```

but when I set full-screen the frame the result is:

---

```
|          |                             |
|          |                             |
|    1     |                             |
|          |                             |
|__________|                             |
|          |             3               |
|          |                             |
|          |                             |
|    2     |                             |
|          |                             |
|__________|_____________________________|
```

How to set sizes of every panel in the frame on full-screen?

Comment: I'd use a `GridBagLayout` [as an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36671093/formatting-jpanels-with-gridbaglayout/36672520#36672520)

Comment: So panels 1 & 2 have equal height & 3 has the same width as the stacked 1 & 2?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a layout manager for the JFrame to use.  A layout manager deals with how components are positioned.  A JFrame's default layout manager is FlowLayout.

A good one to try would be the BorderLayout.

```
yourFrame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
yourFrame.add(yourPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
yourFrame.pack();
```

Comment: The default layout manager of the content pane of the JFrame is the BorderLayout.

Comment: FlowLayout is the default layout manager of J*Panel*. Your answer says (incorrectly) that it's the default layout manager of J*Frame*. In any case, I don't think that a BorderLayout will do what the OP is looking for. BorderLayout doesn't allocate the same width for the left and center components. BorderLayout keeps the left component a fixed size and gives all extra space to the center component.